# Authorize user by user id using spring security instead of roles

Tags: security, spring

I have configured spring security with LDAP is working fine, i am able to grant authority to URL based on Roles, which is also fine, 
I want to grant authority based on Userid along with Role, for example i would like to have authority for one URL for all users in a Role, and then only few users who are not part of that role, can i do it
here is interceptor URL

```
<intercept-url pattern="/displayAirportTiles" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ROLETRSADMINS')"  />
```

I would like to add user id for example like below (This is not working offcourse) but gives idea of what i am trying

```
<intercept-url pattern="/displayAirportTiles" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ROLETRSADMINS') or hasAnyUserid('GUITEST1')" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, using the below setup

```
<intercept-url pattern="/displayAirportTiles" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ROLETRSADMINS') or request.remoteUser == ('GUITEST1')" />
```